# Moving background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across the following website and I was wondering if anyone here knew how the moving background image is being done? Is it a JavaScript plugin, just a regular .gif, etc?

http://kilothought.com/about/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a HTML5 video, if you dig down far enough, you'll find this HTML:

```
<video class="slider-video" width="1602" height="902" preload="auto" loop="" autoplay="" style="visibility: visible; width: 1602px; height: 902px;" src="http://kilothought.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/miami-web-designer-fl.webmhd.webm">
```

So basically, it's a video that loops over and over again

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eY9Gw/

Comment: Do you know of any websites where I can find videos that loop for this purpose?

Comment: I was actually in the process of writing a little JSFiddle for you, here's the link and I've updated my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/eY9Gw/ Pleas contact me if you need some more support

Comment: After a quick Google, here some websites I've found; http://www.movietools.info, http://www.motionbackgroundsforfree.com and http://www.stockfootageforfree.com/looping-backgrounds. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a video background, through this URL: 
[Video Here](http://kilothought.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/miami-web-designer-fl.webmhd.webm)

- Right-Click --> Inspect element

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's just a `video` element placed behind the other elements